# Search through an array for a value and return the value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to search through an array for a value and if the value isn't found then I want to return the max value in an array.

Data looks like below -
(ID is data type STRING, Product_id is data type INTEGER)

```
ID            Product_id
ABC123        1122
              5432
              6099
PQR567        5432
              0793
              1111
LMN789        1111
              2222
              9999
```

So, in this case, I want to search for the value "5432". If the value is found then return that value else return the max value. So, the result should look like-

```
ID          Product_id
ABC123        5432
PQR567        5432
LMN789        9999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ID,
  ( SELECT IF(COUNTIF(id = 5432) = 0, MAX(id), 5432)
    FROM t.Product_id id
  ) AS Product_id
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'ABC123' ID, [1122,5432,6099] Product_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PQR567', [5432,0793,1111] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'LMN789', [1111,2222,9999] 
)
SELECT ID,
  ( SELECT IF(COUNTIF(id = 5432) = 0, MAX(id), 5432)
    FROM t.Product_id id
  ) AS Product_id
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

with output

```
Row ID      Product_id   
1   ABC123  5432     
2   PQR567  5432     
3   LMN789  9999
```

Another slightly different option - just one reference to search value (5432)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ID,
  ( SELECT IFNULL(MAX(IF(id = 5432, id, NULL)), MAX(id))
    FROM t.Product_id id 
  ) AS Product_id
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would write this as:

```
select t.*,
       (select coalesce(max(case when product_id = 5432 then product_id end),
                        max(product_id)
                       )
        from unnest(t.product_ids) product_id
       ) as product_id
from t;
```